# sql conversions in select statement

Tags: sql-server

Here is a table example. using sql-server
I am trying to pull the max(login date) for each employee below, but the "login date" in the database is datatype int.
I can select it easy enough, ie,

```
select employee,title,max(login_date) from employee group by employee,title
```

I can use substring to convert the login_date("YYYYMM") to a date variable,

```
set @var_year=select (substring((select login_date),1,4))
```

using a variable to store the year and a variable to store the month, but how do I pass that to my main select statement?

```
Employee  Title         Login_Date              
-----------------------------------------
Mike      VP            201301
Amy       CEO           201201                    
Joe       Office Mgr    201105
Andy      Admin Asst    201308
Joe       Office Mgr    201205
Andy      Admin Asst    201309
Joe       Office Mgr    201205
Andy      Admin Asst    201309
```

Comment: What is the better way to query it then, because I want the new "date" field to be correct, and not just grabbed from the first result

Comment: can you show the expected results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few ways you could do that.
One would be

```
Select m.employee,m.title,
convert(int,substring(thisisNOTadate,1,4)) as [Year],
convert(int,substring(thisisNOTadate,5,2)) as [Month]
From 
(select employee,title,max(login_date) as ThisisNOTadate 
 from employee group by employee,title
) m
```

Personally after slapping who ever called a string in the format YYYYMM login_date a few times, I'd rework the table so login_date was in fact a date with something like `Convert(DateTime,Convert(VarChar(6), Login_date) + '01')`, and then anything that needed parts of the date could use that standard date functions.

So based on your comment to Mr ReBand earlier then

```
select employee,title,
       max(convert(datetime,Convert(varchar(6),login_date) + '01')) as arealdate
From employee group by employee,title
```

would be another.

Comment: I completely agree Tony. Its a date field in our program, but it goes to an int field in the database. Thanks Tony, I think I can use that.

Comment: I was going to give you a + there Mr Reband. I wasn't happy not putting a style in, and didn't know it would be happy with 126 even without the hyphen separators.

Comment: convert(datetime,Convert(varchar(6),login_date) + '01'),126) for those who can't see deleted posts